# UI template with big controls

Tags: user-interface

Im not sure if this question is appropriate to go in here but after some hard effort in google I had no option but to post this here.

I'm in the process of doing some UIs for a touch screen, but not sure how the template should look like. e.g. how big the buttons/text/labels should be. If anyone has experience in doing s similar stuff, pls share some references you have.

thanks
BB

Comment: Is this on a mobile device, e.g. a smartphone? In that case, there are probably design guidelines somewhere.

Comment: @Thomas, this is a web application that should be shown in a 1024/768 resolution touch screen. But the controls should be quite large for the users as it will be used in a warehouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good guide is to use common sense and taste... :-) Something some Visual Basic programmers (among others) forgot when they discovered they could use any color for the parts of the controls... :-D

The buttons must be big enough to be readable even in bad conditions, and text must be well contrasted. They also must be big enough to be easily selected with a finger. But not too big, I find a button taking a quarter of the screen quite aggressive... And you probably have also a constraint on the number of buttons to fit on the screen...